# simplifying function

Tags: python, string, int, slice, typeconverter

I have wrote this function, i think it would work but im not 100% sure. But im curious this is very complicated. Any way in which i can make this simpler?

The three parameters are times in the form 'HH:MM', where 00 <= HH <= 23 and 00 <= MM <= 59. The first two times are time estimates and the third is the actual time. Return the time estimate, one of the first two parameters, that is closest to the actual time. If they are the equally close, return the first time.

```
(str, str, str) -> str  


def closest_time(guess1, guess2, answer):
    if abs((int(answer[:2])) - (int(guess1[:2])) > ((int(answer[:2])) - int(guess2[:2]))):
        return guess2
    if abs((int(answer[:2])) - (int(guess1[:2])) < ((int(answer[:2])) - int(guess2[:2]))):
        return guess1
    if abs((int(answer[:2])) - (int(guess1[:2])) == ((int(answer[:2])) - int(guess2[:2]))):
        if abs((int(answer[3:])) - (int(guess1[3:])) > ((int(answer[3:])) - int(guess2[3:]))):
            return guess2
        if abs((int(answer[3:])) - (int(guess1[3:])) < ((int(answer[3:])) - int(guess2[3:]))):
            return guess1
        if abs((int(answer[3:])) - (int(guess1[3:])) == ((int(answer[3:])) - int(guess2[3:]))):
            return guess1
```

Answer (score 5):

I would convert from `HH:MM` form to minutes using `m = int(HH) * 60 + int(MM)`.  That should simplify the problem considerably.

Putting it all together:

```
>>> def to_minutes(s):
        return int(s[:2]) * 60 + int(s[-2:])

>>> def closest_time(guess1, guess2, answer):
        g1, g2, a = map(to_minutes, [guess1, guess2, answer])
        return guess1 if abs(g1 - a) <= abs(g2 - a) else guess2

>>> closest_time('08:05', '10:30', '08:10')
'08:05'
>>> closest_time('08:05', '10:30', '10:05')
'10:30'
```

Comment: what if i could not change the form? this is the best i could do?

Comment: Since the notion of "closest" depends on computing the difference between two timestamps, just about **any** correct solution will have to treat the *HH* field as being sixty times the *MM* field.  How else would you know that 09:50 is closer to 10:01 than 10:15?

Comment: Also, FWIW, your original code contained fragments like ``(int(answer[3:])``.  At that point, you've already changed form :-)  There's no getting around converting strings to integers (because strings can't be subtracted) and multiplying hours by 60 (because hours and minutes are two differently scaled measurements of the same physical quantity, time).

Comment: FWIW I'm not sure if by "first time" the question means "guess1" in case of ties or "min((guess1, guess2), key=to_minutes).

Comment: @DSM The last line of the OP's sample code returns *guess1* when the time differences are equal.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: under the circumstances I'm not sure that's dispositive, but I take your point. :)